# Find the least common multiple of multiple numbers

Tags: c, optimization

The goal of this program is to find the smallest number that can be divided by the numbers 1 to 20 without any remainders. The code is working but it takes 33 seconds. Can I improve it so that it can be faster? How?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int number = 19, i, k;

  label:
  number++;
  k = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    if (number%i == 0){
      k++;
    }
  }

  if (k != 20){
    goto label;
  }

  printf("%d\n", number);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could display the numbers 1 to 20 as products of primes and then taking the number that is a product of primes with an the maximal order in the products before. Something like 16*9*5*7*9*11*13*17*19.

Comment: And it also needs to end with 0.

Comment: You can start with 3 * 7 * 10 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 = 9699690 as an initial pointer and check if it divides with 4, 9, 16. if it doesnt, add 9699690 more and test it again.

Comment: There is something you probably learned in elementary school that helps with this. When you were taught to add fractions with different denominators, you had to find a common denominator. Do you remember any of the techniques that were taught about that? If you were adding 1/6+1/10, how would you find the answer?

Comment: I remember but I didn't want to make calculations on the paper. Instead, I want computer to make those calculations. That's the tip I'm looking for my friend.

Comment: By the way, thank you all for your answers. I'll do my best with them.

Comment: Try to avoid `goto`, it may bring you problems in future projects.

Comment: 2x2x2x2x3x3x5x7x11x13x17x19 ... Multiply the max power of each prime less than your number.  That should work for all values (not just 20) but the numbers get big fast so use unsigned long long (or a big number library for really high values).

Comment: @technosaurus There are some great answers in these comments; far better than mine (even if the improvement is significant) - _please_ take the time to actually post an answer!  A more complete explanation would benefit those without the necessary math fu.  For example the phrase _"max power of each prime less than your number"_ might not mean anything to many.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question answered two thousand, three hundred years ago.

Comment: My program to compute and print all the values for numbers from 1 to 46 takes between 6 and 7 milliseconds to print the lot — on an ordinary MacBook Pro.  That code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `lcm20.c` in the [src/miscellany](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/miscellany) sub-directory.

Comment: @isragram May it bring problem if I only use it to break loops? If so, is there a faster way to do it instead of putting multiple breaks for each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int number = 19 ;
```

to

```
int number = 0 ;
```

then:

```
number++;
```

to

```
number += 20 ;
```

is an obvious improvement that will have a significant impact even if it is still a somewhat naive brute force approach.

At onlinegdb.com your algorithm took 102 seconds to run whereas this change runs in less that one second and produces the same answer.

The initial product of primes value suggested in a comment will provide a further improvement.

Comment: I have defined #define PRIMES 11*13*17*19*20 and increment number with PRIMES. And it made it work less than 1 sec! Thank you for the advise. (Sorry about the answering format, still couldn't get used to with it...)

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>


/*  GCD returns the greatest common divisor of a and b (which must be non-zero).

    This algorithm comes from Euclid, Elements, circa 300 BCE, book (chapter)
    VII, propositions 1 and 2.
*/
static unsigned GCD(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    while (0 < b)
    {
        unsigned c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    return a;
}


int main(void)
{
    static const unsigned Limit = 20;

    unsigned LCM = 1;

    /*  Update LCM to the least common multiple of the LCM so far and the next
        i.  The least common multiple is obtained by multiplying the numbers
        and removing the duplicated common factors by dividing by the GCD.
    */
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= Limit; ++i)
        LCM *= i / GCD(LCM, i);

    printf("The least common multiple of numbers from 1 to %u is %u.\n",
        Limit, LCM);
}
```

Comment: I am too new to C to understand this kind of format but thank you, since it gave me a point to start from in order to improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply all the least common multiples together, but omit numbers that could be multiplied to get any of the others.  This translates to multiply by all primes less than N with each prime number raised to the highest power <= N.

```
const unsigned primes[] = {
    2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47
};

unsigned long long answer(unsigned n){ //for your example n=20
    if (n>46) return 0;  //will overflow 64 bit unsigned long long
    unsigned long long tmp, ret = 1;
    for (unsigned i = 0; primes[i]<=n;++i){ //each prime less than n
        tmp = primes[i];
        while ((tmp*primes[i])<=n) //highest power less than n
            tmp *= primes[i];
        ret *= tmp;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

usage: `printf("%llu", answer(20));`

If my math/code is right this should be fast and cover numbers up to 46.  If your compiler supports unsigned __int128 it can be modified to go up to 88.

Explanation:
TLDR version: all numbers are either prime or can be made by multiplying primes.

> To get the least common multiple of a set of numbers you break each
>   number into it's prime multiples and multiply the highest number of
>   each prime together.
>
> Primes less than 20:
>   2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19
>
> Non primes under 20: 
>   4 = 2*2
>    6 = 2*3
>    8 = 2*2*2
>    9 = 3*3
>    10 = 2*5
>    12 = 2*2*3
>    14 = 2*2*7
>    15 = 3*5
>    16 = 2*2*2*2
>    18 = 2*3*3
>    20 = 2*2*5
>
> From this we see that the maximum number of 2s is 4 and the maximum
>   number of 3s is 2.
>
> 2 to the 4th <= 20
>   3 squared <= 20
>   All powers >1 of the remaining
>   primes are greater than 20.
>
> Therefore you get:
>
> 2*2*2*2*3*3*5*7*11*13*17*19
>
> Which is what you would see if you watched the tmp variable in a
>   debugger.
>
> Another reason this is faster is that it avoids modulus and division
>   (It's expensive on a lot of systems)

Comment: You have to do a bit more than just multiply by each prime.  For example, 8 is a power of 2, but you need 2 * 2 * 2 if the LCM is to include 8 as a factor.  Also, you run into precision problems with your 64-bit unsigned numbers after N = 46.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler powers of primes is covered in the while loop... precision on ints though?

Comment: OK; I'll check it out in due course — I'm checking another answer at the moment.  My version of this code from some years ago — available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `lcm20.c` in the [src/miscellany](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/miscellany) sub-directory — finds that the LCM for the numbers up to 46 is 9419588158802421600 (and the same value is the LCM for 44 and 45).  After that, my 64-bit numbers run out of bits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I checked and get overflow starting at 47.

Comment: That’s what I got too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without defining primes or divisions (except for a single sqrt), using a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (circa 200 BCE).

I mark composites with 1, and primes^x with -1. Then i just loop over the array of numbers from sqrt(n) to n and pull out the remaining primes and max power primes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define n 20

int main()
{
    int prime [100]={0};
    int rootN = sqrt(n);
    unsigned long long inc,oldInc;
    int i;
    for (i=2; i<rootN; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i] == 1) continue;
        //Classic Sieve
        inc = i*i;
        while (inc < n)
        {
         prime[inc] = 1;
         inc += i;
        }
        //Max power of prime
        oldInc = i;
        inc = i * i;
        while (inc < n)
        {
         prime[inc] = 1;
         oldInc=inc;
         inc *= i;
        }
        prime[oldInc] = -1;
        prime[i] = 1;

    }
    inc = 1;
    for(i=rootN; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i] == 0 || prime[i] == -1)
        {
            inc = inc * i;
        }
    }

    printf("%llu",inc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This problem overflows 32 bit int at N=23, 64 bit at N=47 and 128 bit at around N=88.  Storing the primes up to 91 takes less than 32 bytes while the code to calculate them will be significantly larger and slower than a lookup that fits in a cache line.  If you start going into BigNum territory then checking primes incrementally starts to make sense, but the calculated results will be HUGE.

Comment: Very true. But if you're mapping the primes, I'd argue that you may as well just map out the powers then. It'll be a little more code and a const array (2d array maybe), but then it's just pulling and multiplying the final answer.